# Python garbage collector does not release images from memory when used with the Tkinter library

Tags: python, tkinter, garbage-collection, python-imaging-library, customtkinter

I'm relatively new to programming, I'm self-taught. I'm trying to create a program for sorting photos (using the keys that the user will select to move the photos to their pre-initialized folders).
My main problem is, when the user presses the key to render the next photo (to view it), the garbage collector will not release the previous photo from memory (even though I am trying to destroy).
I don't know if garbage collector doesn't release the photo from memory, or if it doesn't releases some other, no longer needed objects (or any dependencies).
*strings are written in Czech*

I would be grateful for any answer.

My code:

```
import customtkinter as custk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
import shutil
import threading
import gc

mainWindow = custk.CTk()
custk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
custk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

mainWindow.geometry('1200x800')
mainWindow.title('PhotoSorter 1.0')

mainFrame = custk.CTkScrollableFrame(mainWindow, width=930, height=770)
mainFrame.place(x=1190, y=10, anchor='ne')


def sourceFolderButton_event():
    global sourceFolderPathsList
    global sourceFolderPath
    try:
        sourceFolderPath = filedialog.askdirectory()

        valid_extensions = [".png", ".jpg"]
        files = os.listdir(sourceFolderPath)
        sourceFolderPathsList = [file for file in files if os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() in valid_extensions]
    except: passe
    

sourceFolderButton_Image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.open('mainFiles\\icons\\folder_icon.png').resize((40,40)))
sourceFolderButton = custk.CTkButton(mainWindow, width=225, image=sourceFolderButton_Image, fg_color='#101010', hover_color='#121212', border_width=0, text='hlavní složka', font=('Arial', 15), command=sourceFolderButton_event)
sourceFolderButton.place(x=7, y=745)

checkY = 0
forImgNameCounter = 0
actualIndexOfPath = -1
bindProfile_list = []
img_obj = 0


def rightWayImage(event):
    global img_obj
    if img_obj != 0:
        img_obj.imageLabel.destroy()
        # img_obj.image.close()
        del img_obj
    
    gc.collect()


    global actualIndexOfPath
    if actualIndexOfPath < len(sourceFolderPathsList)-1:
        actualIndexOfPath += 1


    img_obj = soImage(f'{sourceFolderPath}/{sourceFolderPathsList[actualIndexOfPath]}')



def leftWayImage(event):
    global img_obj
    if img_obj != 0:
        img_obj.imageLabel.destroy()
        # img_obj.image.close()
        del img_obj.cu_image
        del img_obj
    
    gc.collect()


    global actualIndexOfPath
    if actualIndexOfPath < len(sourceFolderPathsList)-1:
        actualIndexOfPath -= 1


    img_obj = soImage(f'{sourceFolderPath}/{sourceFolderPathsList[actualIndexOfPath]}')


mainWindow.bind('<Right>', rightWayImage)
mainWindow.bind('<Left>', leftWayImage)

class soImage():
    def __init__(self, image_path):
        self.image_path = image_path
        self.checkRotate = 0
        self.angle = 0
        
        self.imageLabel = custk.CTkLabel(mainFrame, text='')
        self.imageLabel.pack()
        
        self.load_image()

        mainWindow.bind(",", self.rotate_left)  # Bind klávesy pro rotaci doleva
        mainWindow.bind(".", self.rotate_right)  # Bind klávesy pro rotaci doprava
 
    def load_image(self):
        self.image = Image.open(fp=self.image_path)
        self.getSizeHeight()
        self.cu_image = custk.CTkImage(dark_image=self.image, size=(self.width, self.height))
        self.imageLabel.configure(image=self.cu_image)

        

    
    def getSizeHeight(self):
        width, height = self.image.size
        if width > height:
            if self.checkRotate == 1:
                tmp = width
                width = height
                height = tmp

                width = width*(770/height)
                height = height*(770/height)
            else:
                height = height*(920/width)
                width = width*(920/width)  

        elif height > width:
            width = width*(770/height)
            height = height*(770/height)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.checkRotate = 0    

    def rotate_left(self, event):
        self.angle = 90
        self.rotateImg()

    def rotate_right(self, event):
        self.angle = -90
        self.rotateImg()

    def rotateImg(self):
        self.checkRotate = 1
        self.getSizeHeight()
        self.image = self.image.rotate(self.angle, expand=True)
        self.cu_image.configure(dark_image=self.image, size=(self.width, self.height))


class plusFunc():
    def __init__(self, keyBind):
        self.button = custk.CTkButton(mainWindow, width=220, height=27, corner_radius=4, text=keyBind, fg_color='transparent', bg_color='transparent', text_color='#580FF0', border_width=2, border_color='#580FF0', hover=False)
        if checkY == 1:
            self.button.place(x=7, y=50)
        else:
            self.button.place(x=7, y=20+30*checkY)
        self.keyBind = keyBind
        self.location = ''

        mainWindow.bind(self.keyBind, self.keyBind_event)
    
    def keyBind_event(self, event):
        global forImgNameCounter
        def keyBind_eventTHREADdef():
            if self.location == '':
                self.location = filedialog.askdirectory()
            else:
                shutil.copyfile(f'{sourceFolderPath}/{sourceFolderPathsList[actualIndexOfPath]}', f'{self.location}/{sourceFolderPathsList[actualIndexOfPath][:-3]}_{forImgNameCounter}.{sourceFolderPathsList[actualIndexOfPath][-3:]}')
                sourceFolderPathsList.remove(sourceFolderPathsList[actualIndexOfPath])   
        forImgNameCounter += 1
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=keyBind_eventTHREADdef)
        t1.start()
        

def make_bindProfile(key=None):
    if bindProfile_list[0] :
        bindProfile_list.append(key)

 
def plusFuncButton_event():
    toplevelMessage = custk.CTkToplevel(mainWindow)
    toplevelMessage.geometry('350x100')
    toplevelMessage.title('WindowForBind')
    toplevelMessage.attributes('-topmost', 1)
    toplevelMessage.focus_force()

    label = custk.CTkLabel(toplevelMessage, text='Stiskněte libovolnou klávesu pro přiřazení k "bindu"')
    label.pack(anchor='center')

    def key_press(event):
        key = event.keysym
        toplevelMessage.destroy()
        global checkY
        checkY += 1
        plusFunc(key)

    toplevelMessage.bind('<Key>', key_press)


plusFuncButton = custk.CTkButton(mainWindow, width=223, height=30, corner_radius=13, border_width=0, text='přidat bind', text_color='black', font=('Arial', 20), fg_color='#6e2ff2', hover_color='#5F18F1', command= plusFuncButton_event)
plusFuncButton.place(x=7, y=10)


def auto_make(keyBind):
    pass



mainWindow.mainloop()
```

I tried to find some real-time memory tracker for python, but I guess I can't search enough.

soubory [zde](https://github.com/Anonyxl/stuckover.git).

Comment: Tkinter uses the C Tk library. The image is in the C memory, not Python memory.

Comment: Complicated objects are often not deleted immediately, but the next time that the garbage collector is run.  But as a beginning programmer, you should just not worry about this.  Trust Python to do the right thing unless you have some special need for the photo to be purged immediately.

Comment: @Frank Yellin  I'm just trying to see if it can't be done better, because while viewing photos from the camera, where photos are normally 20 MB, with 30 photos it takes up like 5 GB of RAM, which is not nice.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you did not disable automatic garbage collection before calling gc.collect() manually.

I faced the same problem recently and I just added:

```
gc.disable()
gc.collect()
gc.enable()
```

According to [this source](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-garbage-collection/) automatic garbage collection has to be disabled before manual calling :).

A reason why the memory is quickly getting stuffed with all that img data is that the automatic garbage collector face difficulties in recognizing circular references between objects which already lost a reference to a variable in a code.

Eg.:

```
x = tk.Frame()
y = tk.Button(master=x)

x.destroy() # for tkinter x is dead, but because of connection with y it's still alive in the memory.
```

I would add that [GC docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) says "The effect of calling gc.collect() while the interpreter is already performing a collection is undefined." so disabling gc before manual collection is a must :).